# Serialize Custom subclass of CLCircularRegion with extra an property in the class

Tags: swift, nscoding

I am using this class to create an object but when I archive and unarchive from and to UserDefaults it only gives me the value of trialUrl but not it's superclass properties.Since I don't know if CLCircularRegion supports Codable protocol I'm stuck with this approach.

```
class TrialRegion: CLCircularRegion{
        var trailUrl:URL?

         init(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D, radius: CLLocationDistance, identifier: String,trailUrl:URL) {
            super.init(center: center, radius: radius, identifier: identifier)
            self.trailUrl = trailUrl
        }
        override func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
            super.encode(with: aCoder)
            aCoder.encode(URL.self, forKey: "trialUrl")
        }

        required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            super.init(coder: aDecoder)
            guard let url = aDecoder.decodeObject(of: NSURL.self, forKey: "trialUrl") as URL? else {return}
            self.trailUrl = url
        }
    }
```